# imprimir dados do EventEmitter no angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

pessoal me tirem uma duvida eu pesquisei mais não encontrei resposta ainda eu tenho um objeto dentro de um `auth.service`
O código do app.component

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './login/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  authNavShow: boolean = false;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.authService.authNav.subscribe(
      mostrar => this.authNavShow = mostrar,
    );

    console.log(this.authService.userData);

    if(this.authNavShow != true){
      var auth: boolean = true;

    }


  }
}
```

o código do auth.service

```
import { Injectable,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) { }

  private userAuth: boolean = false;

  authNav = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  userData = new EventEmitter();

  fazerLogin(dataLogin){

    this.http.post(`http://localhost:88/login`, 
    JSON.stringify(dataLogin))
    .map(dados => dados.json())
    .subscribe(dados => this.checkLogin(dados)
    );

  }

  checkLogin(dados){

    if(dados.success == true){
      this.userAuth = true ;
      this.authNav.emit(true);

      this.userData.emit(dados);

      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }

  }

  userAuthenticated(){
    return this.userAuth;
  }
}
```

o que eu preciso é puxar os dados do objeto no meu app.component mas não conheço nenhuma forma ou meio, se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço muitoo!

Comment: é preciso um pouco mais de codigo; no entanto, se no teu `app.component.ts` fizeres `subscribe()` ao `service.userData` deverás ter o seu valor

Comment: seria interessante você editar sua pergunta adicionando o código do `app.component.ts` e `auth.service` ao invés de colocar-los como uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `ngOnInit` do teu `app.component.ts` terás que fazer o mesmo que fizeste com o `this.authService.authNav`

```
  ngOnInit(){
        this.authService.userData.subscribe(data => this.userData = data);
        this.authService.authNav.subscribe(mostrar => this.authNavShow = mostrar);
  }
```

depois terás que iniciar um pointer como o `this.authNavShow`, só que com o nome de `userData`

Comment: hehe funcionou, muito obrigado! sou iniciante com o angular 2 ai tenho muitas duvidas ainda, mais um dia eu chego la